# SQL Server Stored Procedure call another Stored Procedure for Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that I pass parameters and get a return based on a Select. I created a second stored procedure that does the same thing except it returns a count.

I was wondering since it seems redundant - how to call the first stored procedure and simply perform a count on it?

What I would like to do.... 
example:

```
execute spRunReportByTime
```

returns:

```
ID User Type
1  abc  123
2  cde  345
```

then I would want to run the second procedure:

```
execute spRunReportByTimeCOUNT
```

it would call spRunReportByTime return the count from that procedure

```
2
```

Right now the second procedure has the same code in it but a Select count(id)

Comment: Have you checked the value of `@@RowCount` after running the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the first stored procedure add following

> ```
> Select @@ROWCOUNT
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can consolidate into one proc that returns the count as an out parameter, or simply adds the count as a new column to the result set?